# traps being sent to rsyslog not in local2 where is conf to set this

Tags: rsyslog, snmp

We have APC gear sending traps to Ubuntu 18.04. trapd is forwarding these to rsyslog AOK (in same host). But unlike Cisco syslogs (from remote Cisco gear)  no usable "Facility" is written when traps land in rsyslog. Cisco sends 'local6'.  Some man pages talk about "
I have read man pages that show that :

```
SNMPDOPTS='=On -Lsd 2 -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf'
```

in  `/etc/systemd/system/snmpd.service.d/local.conf`  can/control setting "Facility."
End goal is pull all syslog to service now for event management.
Thanks for any insight to this

Comment: meuh your edit looks same as my code? Am I not seeing some detail. Thanks